# matplotlib collections update

Tags: python, matplotlib, collections, plot, python-3.5

I wanted to update PatchCollections. I looked at the solution given at [matplotlib change a Patch in PatchCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903554/matplotlib-change-a-patch-in-patchcollection) and I tried to modified to my needs. It works fine without error but it just changes the position of the last rectangle.  I want it to update with all the new rectangles positions.

```
import matplotlib.collections as mcollections
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class UpdatablePatchCollection(mcollections.PatchCollection):
    def __init__(self, patches, *args, **kwargs):
        self.patches = patches
        mcollections.PatchCollection.__init__(self, patches, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_paths(self):
        self.set_paths(self.patches)
        return self._paths

m=[]
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((i,2),1,1)
    m.append(rect)
    rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((i,3),1,1)
    m.append(rect)

# This is just for display purpose and will be commented out        
collection = mcollections.PatchCollection(m)
ax = plt.figure(None).gca()
ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_ylim(0,10)
ax.add_artist(collection)
plt.show()

j = []
for i in range(10):
    rect.set_xy((i,5))
    rect.set_height(2)
    rect.set_width(2)
    j.append(rect)
    print(i)   

print(len(j))
m[:] = j[:]   

collection = UpdatablePatchCollection(m)
ax = plt.figure(None).gca()
ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_ylim(0,10)
ax.add_artist(collection)
plt.show()
```

The result is for the first plt.show() : [image]

Second plt.show() is : [image]
The second loop replaces just the last value.

it is kind of similar to my previous question. If this works out then I'll accept the answer for that as well. Thanks