# Animate a collection of patches in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to animate a set of particles that follow trajectories in x, y and z. Each object has a specific radius which is relevant in axis units, which is why I want each object to be represented by a Circle patch, where I can specify the size of the patch (as opposed to a scatter plot, where I have to convert the size to axis units).

The other constraint is that I want the patches to be colored according to a colormap, with the color of the patch determined by the value of z.

The only way I have found of plotting a set of patches with a colormap is by putting them inside a collection. So, this successfully produces one frame

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anm
import matplotlib.collections as clt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(7,7))

ax.set_xlim(-1,1)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)

n_of_particles = 3
frames = 10

radius = 0.05
x = 0.5*np.random.randn(frames,n_of_particles)
y = 0.5*np.random.randn(frames,n_of_particles)
z = 0.5*np.random.randn(frames,n_of_particles)

patches = []
for p in range(n_of_particles):
    circle = plt.Circle((x[0,p], y[0,p]), radius)
    patches.append(circle)

collection = clt.PatchCollection(patches, cmap=plt.cm.jet, alpha=0.4)
collection.set_array(z[0,:])
collection.set_clim([-1, 1])
plt.colorbar(collection)

ax.add_collection(collection)
```

But how do I animate it?

I have tried to add at the end (instead of `ax.add_collection(collection)`)

```
def animate(frame):
    patches = []
    for p in range(n_of_particles):
        circle = plt.Circle((x[frame,p], y[frame,p]), radius)
        patches.append(circle)

    collection = clt.PatchCollection(patches, cmap=plt.cm.jet, alpha=0.4)
    collection.set_array(z[0,:])

    ax.add_collection(collection)
    return collection,
```

and then:

```
anim = anm.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                               frames=10, interval=100, blit=True)
HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

But it doesn't erase the previous frame.

Ideally, I would prefer to change the position of the patches, instead of redefining them. But I don't know how to modify a collection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea would of course be to add the collection only once to the axes. Then change the artists inside the collection via `collection.set_paths`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anm
import matplotlib.collections as clt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(7,7))

ax.set_xlim(-1,1)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)

n_of_particles = 3
frames = 10

radius = 0.05
x = 0.5*np.random.randn(frames,n_of_particles)
y = 0.5*np.random.randn(frames,n_of_particles)
z = 0.5*np.random.randn(frames,n_of_particles)

patches = []
for p in range(n_of_particles):
    circle = plt.Circle((x[0,p], y[0,p]), radius)
    patches.append(circle)

collection = clt.PatchCollection(patches, cmap=plt.cm.jet, alpha=0.4)
collection.set_array(z[0,:])
collection.set_clim([-1, 1])
fig.colorbar(collection)

ax.add_collection(collection)

def animate(frame):
    patches = []
    for p in range(n_of_particles):
        circle = plt.Circle((x[frame,p], y[frame,p]), radius)
        patches.append(circle)

    collection.set_paths(patches)
    collection.set_array(z[frame,:])

anim = anm.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                               frames=10, interval=1000, blit=False)
plt.show()
```

The other option could be to use the solution provided in this answer: [matplotlib change a Patch in PatchCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903554/matplotlib-change-a-patch-in-patchcollection)
and create an `UpdatablePatchCollection`. This would allow to just update the properties of the original patches inside the loop.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anm
import matplotlib.collections as clt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(7,7))

ax.set_xlim(-1,1)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)

n_of_particles = 3
frames = 10

radius = 0.05
x = 0.5*np.random.randn(frames,n_of_particles)
y = 0.5*np.random.randn(frames,n_of_particles)
z = 0.5*np.random.randn(frames,n_of_particles)

patches = []
for p in range(n_of_particles):
    circle = plt.Circle((x[0,p], y[0,p]), radius)
    patches.append(circle)

class UpdatablePatchCollection(clt.PatchCollection):
    def __init__(self, patches, *args, **kwargs):
        self.patches = patches
        clt.PatchCollection.__init__(self, patches, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_paths(self):
        self.set_paths(self.patches)
        return self._paths

collection = UpdatablePatchCollection(patches, cmap=plt.cm.jet, alpha=0.4)
collection.set_array(z[0,:])
collection.set_clim([-1, 1])
fig.colorbar(collection)

ax.add_collection(collection)

def animate(frame):
    for p in range(n_of_particles):
        patches[p].center = x[frame,p], y[frame,p]   
    collection.set_array(z[frame,:])

anim = anm.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                               frames=10, interval=1000, blit=False)

plt.show()
```