# How to animate a Polygon (defined by arrays) with Python & Matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

Good day !

**Problem explanation:**
I want to animate a Polygon which values I receive from an array (in my simple example it is a moving sqaure). I want to keep the Polygon's x-and y-values mutable. Dont worry about what movement the Polygon does. It is just an example. Working with "set_xy()" like in the solution from '[animation to translate polygon using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341722/animation-to-translate-polygon-using-matplotlib)' is wanted.

**Goal** -> in every animation frame I want to load the Polygon values from the arrays (P1x,P1y,P2x,P2y,...) and update the figure.

**Question:**
In my code I still have problems to work with the patches. I'm trying to update the Polygon values with the index i. How do I have to define the patch? Does this have to be done bevor the animation call?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim(-10,10)
ax.set_ylim(-10,10)

P1x=[0.0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0]
P1y=[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
P2x=[1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5,4.0]
P2y=[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
P3x=[1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5,4.0]
P3y=[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
P4x=[0.0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0]
P4y=[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]

def init():
    return patch,

def animate(i):
    v = np.array([
                [P1x[i],  P1y[i]],  
                [P2x[i],  P2y[i]],  
                [P3x[i],  P3y[i]],
                [P4x[i],  P4y[i]]
                ])
    patch=patches.Polygon(v,closed=True, fc='r', ec='r')

    return patch,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 5), init_func=init,
                              interval=1000, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Bazingaa I reopenened, because the [proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48794016/animate-a-collection-of-patches-in-matplotlib?noredirect=1&lq=1) shows how to update a **collection** of patches. But here there is only one single patch. So a collection is much too complicated for this simple task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need to create the Polygon first and add it to the axes. Inside the animating function you may use the patch's `patch.set_xy()` method to update the vertices of the polygon.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim(-10,10)
ax.set_ylim(-10,10)

P1x=[0.0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0]
P1y=[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
P2x=[1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5,4.0]
P2y=[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
P3x=[1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5,4.0]
P3y=[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
P4x=[0.0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0]
P4y=[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]

P = np.concatenate((np.array([P1x, P2x, P3x, P4x]).reshape(4,1,len(P1x)),
                    np.array([P1y, P2y, P3y, P4y]).reshape(4,1,len(P1x))), axis=1)

patch = patches.Polygon(P[:,:,0],closed=True, fc='r', ec='r')
ax.add_patch(patch)

def init():
    return patch,

def animate(i):
    patch.set_xy(P[:,:,i])
    return patch,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(P.shape[2]), init_func=init,
                              interval=1000, blit=True)
plt.show()
```