# Dynamically update plot of patches without ArtistAnimations in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an external service that, every now and then, triggers the function `callback(points)` — check the code below — in order to update a **Polygon** patch being plotted with `matplotlib`.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

polygon = Polygon([[0, 0]])

patches = []
patches.append(polygon)

collection = PatchCollection(patches, animated=True, alpha=0.4)

ax.add_collection(collection)
ax.autoscale_view(True)

plt.show()


def callback(points):
    polygon.set_xy(points)

    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

However, this is not working... The plot is not being updated. Are `canvas.draw` and `canvas.flush_events` not the right things to call?

I have seen other examples on the web which use `ArtistAnimation` but I cannot use this since I cannot simulate my inputs; rather, they are coming from the external service that calls `callback()`.

How can I make this work? Thanks!

Comment: `polygon` has not been added to the axes. Instead `collection` is the artist in the axes. At this point you need to decide: Do you really need a `PatchCollection` or are you happy with updating the patch (without collection). Unfortunately the solutions would be very different, so it would help to know more about the purpose of this.

Comment: I am happy with updating the patch for now, but am very curious to know how to do it if I had to plot multiple patches too.

Comment: I suppose in the case of a collection you need to fall back to subclass `PatchCollection` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903554/matplotlib-change-a-patch-in-patchcollection).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have tried that example but the plot only displays the last state of the collection. I want to be able to show it as it changes, frame by frame. For some reason none of `plt.draw()`, `fig.canvas.draw()`, or `fig.canvas.flush_events()` seem to make it work...

Comment: To create an animation you may use the `FuncAnimation` class.

Comment: I can't use this because I have no control over the rate at which `callback()` is called...

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest nevermind, I think I got it to work by enabling `plt.ion()`!

Comment: Ok, would it be possible to create a [mcve] of the issue? Possibly you can use a `button_press_event` to trigger the callback for that purpose.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest working on it! Will answer this question when ready :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I modified [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903554/matplotlib-change-a-patch-in-patchcollection) slightly (which makes use of an `UpdatablePatchCollection`) and it works now.

Here is a working minimal example:

```
%matplotlib notebook  # Use this on Jupyter Notebooks

import matplotlib.collections as mcollections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import time


class UpdatablePatchCollection(mcollections.PatchCollection):
    def __init__(self, patches, *args, **kwargs):
        self.patches = patches
        mcollections.PatchCollection.__init__(self, patches, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_paths(self):
        self.set_paths(self.patches)
        return self._paths


plt.ion()

rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((0,0),1,1)
collection = UpdatablePatchCollection([rect])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim(0,5)
ax.set_ylim(0,3)

ax.add_artist(collection)


def update_plot(i):
    rect.set_xy((i,1))

    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()


for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    update_plot(i)
```

This part is important to "*render*" each frame.

```
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

And notice the important `plt.ion()` call. Without it, the plot will not interactively animate the changes to the patch collection.