# Modify a specific patch in a Matplotlib PatchCollection

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's assume that I use a third-party function `magic_plot(data, ax)` that adds a collection of patches to the axes based on the provided data. Let's further assume that I want to change the color of a specific patch that that has been added. How do I do that?

```
from numpy.random import rand

from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def magic_plot(data, ax):
    """
    A third-party plotting function, not modifiable by end-users. 
    """
    lst = []
    for i in range(10):
        patch = Circle((rand(), rand()), rand())
        lst.append(patch)
    collection = PatchCollection(lst)
    ax.add_collection(collection)

ax = plt.gca()
data = rand(100)

# create the plot:
magic_plot(data, ax)

# obtain the PatchCollection created by magic_plot():
collection = ax.collections[0]
```

As shown above, I can retrieve the collection from the axes from `ax.collections`, but how do I proceed from here?

I assume that I need to access the list of patches that are stored in this `PatchCollection` object. However, in an answer to a similar question ["matplotlib change a Patch in PatchCollection"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903554/), it has been suggested to use a subclass of `PatchCollection` that tracks the patches that are added to it in a public list attribute, but given that the collection is created in a third-party function, this solution is not an option in my case.

Comment: Is the question how to change the color of a member of a collection? That is totally different from changing the shape/position (for which the linked question gives an answer).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Yes, the question is how to change to color of a member of a collection. I thought that the linked question was related enough to that problem. Would you suggest to remove that reference?

Comment: I edited the question only minimally, but I think this small change would be crucial, please verify that this is the case.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Thanks for your edit. I've made the first sentence even more concise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating the shape of the patches is hardly possible, as shown in the linked question. However, here you want to change the color of a patch. This should be much easier.

In the concrete example from the question, it will be achieved simply by setting the `facecolor` of the collection.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(50)

from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

def magic_plot(data, ax):
    """
    A third-party plotting function, not modifiable by end-users. 
    """
    lst = []
    for i in range(10):
        patch = Circle((np.random.rand(), np.random.rand()), np.random.rand()/9)
        lst.append(patch)
    collection = PatchCollection(lst)
    ax.add_collection(collection)

ax = plt.gca()
data = np.random.rand(100)

# create the plot:
magic_plot(data, ax)
ax.autoscale()

# obtain the PatchCollection created by magic_plot():
collection = ax.collections[0]

n = len(collection.get_paths())
facecolors = collection.get_facecolors()
if len(facecolors) == 1 and n != 1:
    facecolors = np.array([facecolors[0]] * n)

# change the facecolor of the fourth patch (index=3)
facecolors[3] = mcolors.to_rgba("crimson")
collection.set_facecolor(facecolors)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, so the trick is to retrieve a list with the current colors of the patches by calling `get_facecolors()` for the collection, modifying those colors that need changing, and then pass the whole list again to `set_facecolors()`. Thanks, I wouldn't have thought of that.