# Python Matplotlib: Animating a rotating PatchCollection

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I am trying to make an animation in which a `PatchCollection` rotates around the origin. The easiest way seems to be through using a `FuncAnimation`.

As per the answer on [matplotlib change a Patch in PatchCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903554/matplotlib-change-a-patch-in-patchcollection) I am using an extension of the `PatchCollection` class which allows me to update the positions of the individual patches.

The animation function simply calls one of the class methods and returns the collection which is updated:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

grid = HexagonalGrid()

ax.add_collection(grid)

def animate(frame):
    grid.rotateGrid(0.1)
    return (grid,)
    
anim = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, blit=True)
```

When using `RegularPolygon` patches all works fine:

```
class HexagonalGrid(UpdateablePatchCollection):    
    def __init__(self, latticeParameter = 5):
        self.patches = self._initiatePatches(hexRadius)
        UpdateablePatchCollection.__init__(self, self.patches, match_original=True, animated=True)

    def _initiatePatches(self, hexRadius):
        patches = []
        for :
            #calculates the correct starting position for each patch
            patches.append(self._createHex(x,y,hexRadius))
        
    def _createHex(self, x,y, hexRadius):
        return matplotlib.patches.RegularPolygon(
            (x, y),
            numVertices = 6,
            radius = hexRadius,
            orientation = 0,
            fc = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), # fill colour RGBA (black and transparent)
            ec = 'black' # edge colour
        )

        def rotateGrid(self, angle):
        for patch in self.patches:
            x, y = patch.xy
            xNew = x * math.cos(angle) - y * math.sin(angle)
            yNew = x * math.sin(angle) + y * math.cos(angle)
            patch.xy = (xNew, yNew)
            patch.orientation = patch.orientation + angle
```

But when trying to do this with `Rectangle` patches which is the same class except for the following functions:

```
    def _createRectangle(self, x, y, width, height):
        return matplotlib.patches.Rectangle(
            (x, y),
            width,
            height,
            fc=(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
            ec='black',
            animated=True
        )

    def rotateGrid(self, angle):
    for patch in self.patches:
        x, y = patch.xy
        xNew = x * math.cos(angle) - y * math.sin(angle)
        yNew = x * math.sin(angle) + y * math.cos(angle)
        patch.xy = (xNew, yNew)
        patch.angle = patch.angle + angle
```

The rectangles are not rotated with the grid

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHPVs.png)

(For clarity: I expected the rectangles to be rotated 45 degrees as well)

I have already tried replacing the rotation by
`patch.set_transform(patch.get_transform() + matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D().rotate(angle))`  but this had some very strange behavior by moving and enlarging the patches.

Does anyone know a way to make the rectangles rotate?

Answer (score 0):

After some research into the matplotlib source-code I found out what the problem was. In case anyone else encounters the same or a similar problem please read the solution below and see if it will help you!

In the last part of my post I already mentioned the possible use of the `Rectangle.set_transform()` function. The problem lies in the subsequent calls of this setter function.

Because I wanted to modify my existing transform I used the getter `Rectangle.get_transform()` to which I added another transform.
For some reason the getter of the transform of `Rectangle` (but it might be the case for all `Patches`) does not return the set value. That is:

```
t = some_transformation
rect = Rectangle(x,y,width,height)
rect.set_transform(t)
print(rect.get_transform() == t)
```

prints `False`

The correct getter to use in this case would be `rect.get_data_transform()` after which subsequent transforms can be added.